# Bootstrap collapse not displaying content

Tags: html, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a collapse section in react just exactly like it says in Bootstrap v5 documentation, triggered by a button:

```
    <div class = 'lower-part'>
         <div class="interract-icons">
            { ... }
         </div>
         <div class='comment-section'>
             <button class="btn btn-primary comments-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false">
                        See comments... <span><i class="far fa-comments"></i></span>
             </button>  
             <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Don't know if it's anything related to this but all parent divs have `height: auto`.
Does it have anything with jQuery, I saw that older version needed to have jQuery library imported, but I'm pretty sure I saw examples on internet that didn't have any jQuery inserted, but anyway just to be safe I also imported this in `index.html` and still not working:
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the javascript libs of boostrap to make that work. Did you import these?

Comment: The js-parts of bootstrap requires also jquery: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: indeed, i was missing the jquery imports, thank you very much